# jQuery - setting dropdown option as selected when creating dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am iterating through populating a single select dropdown menu using jQuery:

```
if(users_inf === text){
    mySelect.append(
         $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text)
    );
}else{
    $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text)
}
```

What I am trying to do is set a option as '**selected**' when `users_info` matches `text`.

I'm assuming I would use:

`.prop('selected', true);`

However, I have tried:

`$('<option></option>').val(text).html(text).prop('selected', true);`

But no joy - any advice welcomed!

Comment: Is it a single-select or a multi-select?

Comment: It's a single select dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, the old ways are the best:

```
var opt = new Option(text);
opt.selected = users_inf === text;
mySelect[0].options.add(opt);
```

Live Example:

```js
doOne($("#single"), "one");
doOne($("#multi"), "one");
doOne($("#single"), "two");
doOne($("#multi"), "two");
doOne($("#single"), "three");
doOne($("#multi"), "three");

function doOne(mySelect, text) {
  var opt = new Option(text);
  opt.selected = true;
  mySelect[0].options.add(opt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="single"></select>
<hr>
<select id="multi" size=10 multiple></select>
```

---

That said, the jQuery way works too:

```
  $("<option></option>")
      .val(text)
      .html(text)
      .prop('selected', users_inf === text)
      .appendTo(mySelect);
```

...which makes me wonder if something else is going on.

```js
doOne($("#single"), "one");
doOne($("#multi"), "one");
doOne($("#single"), "two");
doOne($("#multi"), "two");
doOne($("#single"), "three");
doOne($("#multi"), "three");

function doOne(mySelect, text) {
  $("<option></option>").val(text).html(text).prop('selected', true).appendTo(mySelect);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="single"></select>
<hr>
<select id="multi" size=10 multiple></select>
```

Comment: Is it me or does both yours and Steve's working solutions seem a little weird??? Not that they don't work but seem counter intuitive?  However, it is likely that it is just me!!!

Comment: @Homer_J: "Weird" how?

Comment: As I say, I think it is just me making assumptions.  I wouldn't have thought to add the "appendTo" option - I'm clearly making the wrong assumptions!

Comment: @Homer_J Using `.append( ... )` is fine too :-)

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to set the `selected` option to `selected` not true. Weird, I know.

So your function would be:

```
if(users_inf === text){
    mySelect.append(
         $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text).attr("selected","selected");
    );
} else {
    $('<option></option>').val(text).html(text)
}
```

Comment: That's true of the *attribute*, not the *property*. The OP is using the *property*.

Comment: Need to use .prop but, yep, odd as you say!

Comment: Hmm, most odd - that doesn't work - I wonder if something in my other code is stopping it.

Comment: Yep, my code was stopping this working - sorted now.  Thank you!

Comment: @Steve: It's *either* `.prop("selected", true)` or `.attr("selected","selected")`, not `.prop("selected","selected")` (your current answer) or `.attr("selected",true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would have done it:

```js
$(function () {
  var values = ["bad", "bad", "good", "bad"];

  $(values).each(function () {
    $("#mySelect").append("<option value=\"" + this + "\">" + this + "</option>");
  });
  
  $("#mySelect option[value='good']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect"></select>
```